# unregister or register models conditionally in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

Is it possible to conditionally register or unregister models in django admin?
I want some models to appear in django admin, only if request satisfies some conditions. In my specific case I only need to check if the logged in user belongs to a particular group, and not show the model if the user (even if superuser) is not in the group. I can not use permissions here because, superusers can not be ruled out using permissions.
Or, is there a way to revoke permission from even superusers on model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permissions on a model can be managed dynamically in `ModelAdmin`.
Override the methods `has_add_permission`, `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission`.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self,request):
        # if request satisfies conditions:
        #   return True
        #else:
        #   return False
```

Same goes for other two methods. This works for `superuser`s also.
If you revoke all three permissions `MyModel` will not be listed on admin site.

If you only require to hide `model` entry from admin site, simply override
`get_model_perms` method. You don't have to override permission methods.

```
def get_model_perms(self, request):
    return {}
```

However, this method does not revoke permissions from the `model`. Even if the model is not listed on admin site, it can be accessed by entering url.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple of approaches locally, including overriding an AdminSite, but given the fact that all admin-related code is loaded when the app is initialized, the simplest approach would be to rely on permissions (and not give everyone superuser access).

Comment: It is not that everyone has superuser access. I actually want to remove/hide many models from superuser accounts which are uselessly hanging there.